# Not seeing stacktrace in Instruments

Tags: iphone, memory, instruments, memory-leaks

I am using Instruments to find memory leaks in my iPhone application. I saw a few leaks in the application however the extended details view is not showing the stacktrace. It just says "No stack trace available for this block".

I am sure I have missed some settings which resulted in this behavior. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks
Jugs

Answer (score -1):

Another method for finding leaks and other coding semantic problems is the Clang static analyzer which can be found here over your code
http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/

Hopefully will find the leak for you